# Is there a way identify character strings irrespective of character order/capitalization, and then group similar observations?

Tags: r, string, character, identity

Sorry if my title is not clear. I have somewhat messy data which includes a "type" variable column. Each observation in this column has two unique character strings, separated by an "x" (this variable actually represents a genotype). Here's some made-up data to illustrate what this "type" variable column is like:

```
df[,1:2]

   ID type
   1   abc x 1
   2   Abc x 1
   3   aBC x 1
   4   1   x abc 
   5   1   x aBc
```

This column contains only character values. What I would like to accomplish is to group observations in the "type" column irrespective of variable order and case into some uniform "type" identifier.

So, using my example data, let's say I want to collect all the observations with the "type" variable equaling "abc" (irrespective of case) AND "1" or "1" AND "abc" (again, irrespective of case) into a single type observation, "abc x 1". This is what I'd like my new data to look like:

```
ID type
1  abc x 1
2  abc x 1 
3  abc x 1 
4  abc x 1
5  abc x 1
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with the `stringr` package and regex:

```
df$type <- tolower(df$type)
df$type <- paste(str_extract(df$type, '^[a-z]+|[a-z]+$'),
                 ' x ',
                 str_extract(df$type, '^\\d+|\\d+$'))

df
  ID      type
1  1 abc  x  1
2  2 abc  x  1
3  3 abc  x  1
4  4 abc  x  1
5  5 abc  x  1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
df$type=gsub("([0-9]+)\\s+(x)\\s+([a-z]+)","\\3 \\2 \\1",tolower(df$type))
```

which returns:

```
df
  ID    type
1  1 abc x 1
2  2 abc x 1
3  3 abc x 1
4  4 abc x 1
5  5 abc x 1
```